# Use JS to convert URL #fragment BEFORE it gets lost to 301 redirect?

Tags: javascript, redirect

In real trouble here. Our old website featured a gallery slider that used URL #fragments to position a jQuery slider on the right project.

For instance, `/work/interactive#777` brought you to the /work/interactive page--which shows one project at a time in a slider--and then animates the slider to project with the ID of `777`

We are about ready to launch a new website with the same projects, but the projects are now fully qualified and independent pages, so the previous project on the new website is at `/work/777`

The big issue is we need to serve 301 redirects for the following:

From: `/work/interactive` To: `/our-work`

AND if there is a hash, somehow capture it before its lost, so after the redirect we can use Javascript to act on the #ID of the project.

I seem to only be able to do one or the other: 301 redirect the root page w/o the #fragments (which prevents me from then checking the #fragment), OR use a global javascript to check the URL and #fragment and use `window.location` to redirect to the individual project page on the new site (which prevents me from any 301 redirects).

Any ideas on how to preserve the #fragment? Is there a way to conditionally perform a 301 if and only if the request URL does NOT have a #fragment?

Comment: Have you tried using a 301 redirect in your .htaccess file or does it have to be in JS?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially where I'm putting the "base" 301 redirects, like `contact-us` to `contact` and `work/interactive` to `our-work`. However as soon as those fire, I lose the hash and can't target a project.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can use htaccess to parse the url for the hash value using some clever regex, store the hash and add it back to the url. I'm terrible with htaccess so I'll have to leave that to you to figure out.

Comment: I've been looking all day, but haven't uncovered any .htaccess + 301 redirect way of accessing or storing fragments, because again and again the answers are 'the fragments never get sent to the server!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible since the browser does not pass the fragment part to the server meanwhile only the server can do 301 redirects.

I'd suggest you to keep the current website URL for this specific case if you need to keep old hyperlinks working.

Comment: Yeah, that's the big problem. No way to 'delay' a 301 redirect, or automatically trigger it after Javascript has a chance to process the URL, or save a cookie?

Comment: @atwixtor I can't see any way to do this. The browser receives the HTTP request, responds it with your client-side information (which includes your JS code) and then closes the connection. After that, the server can't contact the user about the same request again, hence now you can only redirect the user using JavaScript. However, search engines would not be affected by this client-side redirection.

Comment: I'd suggest you to keep the current website URL for this specific case if you need to keep old hyperlinks working.

Comment: I like that idea, even though it means adjusting our approved new path names. That would avoid the need for 301 redirects, and would allow me to process the carried-over fragment in Javascript once the visitor lands.

Comment: @Guilherme_Sehn if you're able to post your last comment here as an answer I"ll accept it. That was definitely the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible (now). However there may still be some older browsers that do not follow the specification: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2

**The solution:**

***First***, set up a server 301 redirect so that all requests to `/work/interactive` will be sent to `/our-work`.

***Second***, put the following JavaScript code at the top of the HTML page at `/our-work`. The code will look at the fragment by using `window.location.hash`, and if not empty, will redirect to `/our-work/xxx` based upon the fragment found. I'm using the `replace` function instead of `assign` so that the browser history does not remember the initial request with a fragment. And since `window.location.hash` will start with `#`, I use `substring(1)` to remove the first character.

```html
<script>
  if (window.location.hash !== "") {
    window.location.replace(window.location.pathname + "/" + window.location.hash.substring(1));
  }
</script>
```

This should work even if `/our-work` is a valid page (e.g. a listing page for all products). Anyone requesting the product listing page without a fragment would not be redirected. A product listing page would also allow search engines to quickly find and re-index the content in its new location.

**Expected behaviour:**

A request for `/work/interactive#777` should initially be redirected by the server (e.g. `301`), and a compliant browser would initially request `/our-work#777`. The server would reply with the HTML/JS code block (and preferably also other fallback HTML content). Depending on performance, the user may briefly see some of the other HTML content before the JavaScript is executed. Then the browser will be redirected to `/our-work/777` and the intended HTML page loaded.

Alternatively, a request for `/work/interactive` (i.e. no fragment) should be redirected by the server, and the browser would then request `/our-work`. The server would reply with the HTML/JS code block and preferably also other fallback HTML content. Since there is no fragment, the HTML/JS code block should do nothing. The user would only see the fallback HTML content (e.g. a product listing page).

**Assumptions:**

- **Every possible fragment has a valid page at `/our-work/xxxx`**. For the code example above, we redirect regardless of what the fragment contains. If you'd prefer to redirect only some fragments, you could use a more specific test, e.g.: `if (/^[#]([0-9]{3}$)/.test(window.location.hash)) { ... }`. This would only redirect for strictly 3-digit numeric fragments. Or adjust the regular expression to your circumstances.
- **Your new page doesn't have content that warrants its own fragments**. If your new page should handle its own fragments (e.g. `/our-work#intro`, `/our-work#portfolio`, etc.), then you'll need to use a more specific test to only selectively redirect (*see previous assumption*).
- **The fragments don't encode additional information**. You could do further processing before redirecting if the fragments contain more complex data. For example, you could parse requests like: `/work/interactive#777-description`, or `/work/interactive#777-author`, and then redirect to `/our-work/777#description` or `/our-work/777#author`.

**Further explanation:**

If a client (e.g. browser) wishes to load `http://www.example.com/old.html#fragment`, it would typically first make a request for `/old.html` from the server at `www.example.com`. If that resource is available at that location, then once received, the client would look for the fragment and adjust (e.g. scroll viewport) if the fragment is found.

However, when the server indicates that the resource has moved by sending a HTTP response of `301`, `302`, etc. and a new `Location` (e.g. `/new.html`), then the client should first make a new request to `/new.html`, and then once received, should still process the fragment and adjust. This implies that after redirecting, the browser address bar should show `http://www.example.com/new.html#fragment`.

Historically, not all browsers have correctly kept the fragment after redirection.

Also note that according to the specification, a browser should give precedence to any fragment specified in the HTTP response `Location` (e.g. `Location: /new.html#newfragment`). And if no fragment is specified in the `Location`, then it should retain any fragment originally requested.